# Display a blank form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie in Rails and I'm developing an app that needs to display a patients info in a form to be updated by a doctor if needed. As soon I can select a patient from a list from sidebar I want to display first just an empty form and when a patient is selected all the info will be displayed on it.

The only way I can guess to do it is to first display the form empty and then, once the patient is selected, catch the patient on the controller and reload the page to allow the form to get the patient info.

Does anybody has a better idea? On negative answer: how can I display an empty form?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Best regards.

**Update:** This is the form I'm trying to present on the page. @patient is an instance variable that once the page is displayed is not defined yet . It will be displayed once the doctor will select one patient from a list on the side.

```
<div class="row">                                                                               
  <div class="span6">                                                                           
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>                                                      
    <div>                                                                                       
    <%= form_for(@patient) do |p| %>                                                            
      <%= text_field_tag 'patient[name][]', nil, :placeholder => "name", :style =>height:12px;font-size:10px;" %>                                                                             
      <%= text_field_tag 'patient[name][]', nil, :placeholder => "surname", :style =>"height:12px;font-size:10px;" %>                                                                          
      <%= p.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email", :style => height:12px;font-size:10px;" %>                                                                                              
    <%= p.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "phone", :style => height:12px;font-size:10px;" %>                                                                         
      <%= check_box_tag :active %>                                                              
      <%= check_box_tag :sex, 'male' %>                                                         
      <%= check_box_tag :sex, 'female' %>                                                       

      <%= chack_box_tag :dao %>                                                                 
      <%= p.submit "Sumbit", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right", id: "boton" %>      
    <% end %>                                                                                   
    </div>                                                                                      
  </div>                                                                                        
</div>
```

An here is the problem. As @patient=nil on the controller since on is selected page crashes.

Thanks again.

Comment: whatever you have tried, please paste here code.

Comment: Hi, the code I insert to the page is the next one:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing here are basic controller actions on your model:

- Empty Form: #new action on Patients controller
- Filled Form: #edit action on Patients controller

**Edit: New Strategy to Accomplish Your Proposed UX**

*Component 1: Nav List of Existing Patients*

1. Iterate over collection of patient objects, outputting a link for each patient to its edit view: `link_to patient.name, edit_patient_path(patient)`
2. This nav view will be a partial that you will include in the view templates for the PatientsController #new action and #edit action.

*Component 2: Empty Form for Nonexistent/New Patient*

1. In controller new action, instantiate a new Patient object, like so `@patient = Patient.new`.
2. Render the patient form on that @patient instance variable, as you do in the view code above.
3. Include the nav list of existing patients as a view partial.

*Component 3: Filled Form for Existing Patient*

1. In controller edit action, instantiate the Patient instance variable, like so `@patient = Patient.find(params[:id])`.
2. Render the patient form on that @patient instance variable, as you do in the view code above.
3. Include the nav list of existing patients as a view partial.

**Edit: Old Points on Scaffolding**

I would strongly suggest using rails generators and scaffolding to set up basic forms and view templates, at least as an educational pursuit. You will, via the command line, be able to automatically generate the proper controller actions and view templates you are describing above for #new and #edit.

Read this article: http://viget.com/extend/rails-3-generators-scaffolding

Then follow this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3

As you become more comfortable with Rails development, generators and scaffolding will likely not satisfy you and needs for customization. They are, however, a great starting point.

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks a lot for your answer but it's not a problem of controlling scaffolding or controller/action generation. My question is about presenting a blank form in a page I actually have some forms in the app working perfectly but I need this specific thing.

Comment: Okay, I'll flesh out my answer with regards to the #new action.

Comment: All you have to do is link to `new_patient_path` and the controller will take care of the rest.

Comment: Alternately, try going to `http://yourhost/patients/new` and let me know if the form renders correctly. If not, you don't have your patient#new action set up correctly, either in controller or view.

Answer (score 1):

I think, one more option is you can Instantiate your object on your form itself:

```
<%= form_for(Patient.new) do |p| %>
```

Thanks